# Column Action - How can I disable Filter Column?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

My page has Interactive Grid

I can apply the other options to disable functions, but cannot disable Filter.
[image]

The JavaScript Code item for each column [Interactive Grid disappear when I add (filter : false) ]

```
 function (config) {  config.features = { canHide: false, compute: false, groupBy: false, highlight: false, pivot: false, sort: true , filter: false};   return config;}
```

Everything works except Filter Column.

Is there a way to disable Filter column header click actions ?

Comment: I think there is a setting for this. Go to page designer >> that column in you interactive grid >> find something like "filter" >> set to "no"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the column, find the "Column Filter" settings, then set *Enabled* to No.

[image: settings]

This can also resolve performance issues, regarding *LOV Type*.

Answer (score 0):

Go to column attribute > advanced > javaScript Initialization code >

```
function(config) {
config.defaultGridColumnOptions = {
    noHeaderActivate: true
};
return config; }
```